# Filter DataView by Numeric field

Tags: vb.net

With my Table1 access I have 5 fields:

> COMPANY_Id Numeric Type,
>
> COMPANY_Ordre Numeric Type,
>
> COMPANY_Total Numeric Type,
>
> COMPANY_Name Text Type,
>
> COMPANY_Date Text Type

When I make a filter by COMPANY_Total, COMPANY_Name, or COMPANY_Date, then the filter works. But with the same type Numeric of fields (COMPANY_Ordre) it does not work.

This is my code of filter dataView:

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim Dv_Filtre As DataView = DT.DefaultView
        Dv_Filtre.RowFilter = "Convert( [COMPANY_Ordre], 'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR Convert( [COMPANY_Total], 'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR [COMPANY_Name] LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR [COMPANY_Date] LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

[Picture Of two numeric field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTs0s.jpg)

Comment: What is Convert doing? Convert is a class and you must call a method of the class but I don't think that will work inside a string. How is one number "Like" another number? How is one date "Like" another date. Dates should always be stored as dates not Text.

Comment: Thank you Mary for explanation.but it work very well with all field only  COMPANY_ordre

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the % also before the textbox1 to get much more results not only data that ONLY ends with specific criteria, such as this:

```
Dv_Filtre.RowFilter="Convert([COMPANY_Ordre],'System.String') LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR ...
```

I hope this can help you brother 
^_^

[image]

Comment: Thank you.I had the same result.Always with only this field ( COMPANY_Ordre ) it does not work .. this field is filled by only one number like this for example 19 rows (1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3 ).

Comment: I see now bro, so that's why? thanks for sharing.   ^_^